# Java mouse hover event while left mouse key is pressed

Tags: java, swing, keyevent

In a panel I've got 10*10 togglebutton. My goal is to do this event:
If left mouse key is down and the mouse is over the specific button call "click on the button" line. So the user can select (click on) multiple buttons easily.

This is not working (changing the same button instead of changing anothers when the mouse is moved):

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JToggleButton;

public class ButtonClickOnHover {
    public void clickOnButtonOnHover(JToggleButton button) {
        button.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                button.doClick(0);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Tried this, not working (what is wrong with his implementation?):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ButtonClickOnHover {
    public void clickOnButtonOnHover(JPanel panel) {
        panel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {



    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        Point location = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        JPanel parent = (JPanel) e.getComponent();
        SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(location, parent);
        Component mouseOver = parent.findComponentAt( location );

        if (mouseOver instanceof JToggleButton)
        {
            JToggleButton button = (JToggleButton)mouseOver;
            button.setBackground( Color.YELLOW );
        }
    }

});

}
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand this concept. As you drag the mouse across the toggle button you will be continuously generating mouseDragged events for the toggle button which means you will keep invoking the doClick() method for every pixel you move.

Comment: I want to invoke doClick() for only the button which is currently in hover.

Comment: But instead of doClick() it is also OK for me if the code change the background color of the button to yellow (so we can avoid togglebutton on/off problem)

Comment: So you want to be able to select a region and trigger the buttons within it?

Comment: @lipilocid, Did you do any debugging? Did you add any System.out.println(..) statements to your code to see if your code is being executed? Post a proper [mcve] demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the mouseDragged event will always be the component where you first generated the mousePressed event, even if you move the mouse over another component.

If you want to know what component the mouse is currently over then you will need to do some extra work.

Something like:

```
Point location = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
Component button = e.getComponent();
JPanel parent = (JPanel)button.getParent();
SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(location, parent);
Component mouseOver = parent.findComponentAt( location );

if (mouseOver instanceof JToggleButton)
{
    JToggleButton button = (JToggleButton)mouseOver;
    button.setBackground( Color.YELLOW );
}
```

The above code attempts to convert the mouse location on the screen to find the component it is currently over.

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but it is not working. What is wrong with my code (see above)?

Comment: Why are you adding the listener to the panel? I didn't suggest doing that anywhere. If you add the listener to the panel, then you don't need to use the "getParent()" method since you already have the reference to the panel containing all the buttons as the source of the MouseEvent. So your suggestion to just add a listener to the panel is reasonable, but I'm not sure if the event will get passed to the panel. The toggle button may have its own MouseMotionListener.

Comment: I just tried to resolve JPanel parent = e.getComponent(); if I cast it to JPanel error is thrown in runtime: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JToggleButton cannot be cast to javax.swing.JPanel
 at ButtonClickOnHover$1.mouseDragged(ButtonClickOnHover.java:24)

Comment: If I change it to component: Component parent = e.getComponent(); than I cant use findComponentAt

Comment: As I said the code wasn't tested, but you need to understand the concept. The listener is added to the toggle button so the e.getComponent() will return the toggle button. Then you need to get the parent of the toggle button which will be a JPanel (I assume). In my original code I forget to add the getParent() method. I changed the code to do this in two steps to better help you understand the process.